# Where to put 'directly' in this sentence

Tags: word-order

I wonder what is the right position of 'directly' in this sentence.

> You can't get this skill **directly** at your birth.

or

> You can't get this skill at your birth **directly**.

I prefer the former one, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these are at all idiomatic, unfortunately. You don't talk about "getting a skill", and neither do you talk about things happening "at your birth" (except for, well, the process of being born).

An idiomatic way of saying this would be:

> You aren't born with this skill.

but you could also say:

> You don't have this skill from the moment you're born.

Answer (score 0):

The first is an absolute indicator, there is no way to get the skill at birth. The second allows for there being some possible indirect way of obtaining the skill at birth.